# Showing $\frac{1}{2L}\|\nabla f(x)\|^2 \leq f(x)-f(x^*).$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

If $\nabla f$ has a Lipschitz constant of $L$, then

$$f(y) \leq f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T(y − x) + \frac{L}{2}\|
y − x\|^2. $$

Using this fact I am going to prove 
$$\frac{1}{2L}\|\nabla f(x)\|^2 \leq f(x)-f(x^*).$$

I started by writing the following statement,

$$ f(x)-f(x^*)=\arg \max_y[f(x)-f(y)]\geq \arg\max_y[-\nabla f(x)^T(y-x)-\frac{L}{2}\|y-x\|^2].$$

However, I don't know how to find "$\arg\max_y[-\nabla f(x)^T(y-x)-\frac{L}{2}\|y-x\|^2]$. I appreciate any help.

Comment: What is $x^*$? Is $f$ convex? You can't mix $\arg\max$ and function  values as you have in the last few lines.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, f is a convex function and $\nabla f$ has a Llipschitz constant of $L$.

Comment: @copper.hat That's the optimal value for function $f$ which minimize $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This result does not depend on $f$ being convex.

Let $\phi_x(h) = \langle \nabla f(x), h \rangle + {L \over 2} \|h\|^2$
and note that $\phi_x$ is a convex quadratic function and $\nabla \phi_x(h) = \nabla f(x) + L h$, hence
$\phi_x(h^*) \le \phi_x(h)$ where $\nabla f(x) + L h^* = 0$.

In particular, $\phi_x(h^*) = -{1 \over 2L} \| \nabla f(x) \|^2$.

We have
$f(x+h) \le f(x) + \phi_x(h)$ and so
$\inf_{h'} f(x+h') = \inf f \le f(x) + \phi_x(h)$ for all $h$.

Hence $\inf f \le f(x) + \inf_h \phi_x(h) = f(x) - {1 \over 2L} \| \nabla f(x) \|^2$.

Rearranging gives
${1 \over 2L} \| \nabla f(x) \|^2 \le f(x) - \inf f$.